# Не работает команда

Tags: python, telegram-bot

По какой причине не работает команда help? В то время как регистрация работает

```
import telebot
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')

# Подключаемся к Базе Данных
db = sqlite3.connect('server.db', check_same_thread=False)
cu = db.cursor()

# Создаём таблицу если она ещё не создана
cu.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    user_id INT,
    cash INT
)""")
db.commit()




    
# Создаём функцию, которая срабатывает при любом входящем сообщении
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def echo_all(message):
    # Если пользователя в БД нету
    cu.execute(f"SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_id={message.from_user.id}")
    if cu.fetchone() is None:
        # Сохраняем его ID в БД
        cu.execute(f"INSERT INTO user VALUES(?, ?)", (message.from_user.id, 0))
        db.commit()

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{message.from_user.first_name}, я успешно зарегистрировал тебя в Базе Данных!')

@bot.message_handler(commands="help")
def send_help(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Добро пожаловать {message.from_user}!")


# Запускаем бота
bot.polling()
```

Comment: А если commands='help'  написать так: commands=['help']

Comment: @Tehnorobot Это не помогает.

Comment: Скорее всего это связано с тем, что вы отлавливаете запросы в echo_all. Попробуйте просто оставить обработчик help

Comment: А функцию, которая срабатывает при любом входящем сообщении закомментировать.

Comment: Не сильно понимаю как это осуществить

Comment: Просто удалите вот эти строки:  
# Создаём функцию, которая срабатывает при любом входящем сообщении
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def echo_all(message):
    # Если пользователя в БД нету
    cu.execute(f"SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_id={message.from_user.id}")
    if cu.fetchone() is None:
        # Сохраняем его ID в БД
        cu.execute(f"INSERT INTO user VALUES(?, ?)", (message.from_user.id, 0))
        db.commit()

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{message.from_user.first_name}, я успешно зарегистрировал тебя в Базе Данных!')

Comment: @Tehnorobot Работает, но Бд теперь же нету

Comment: @FiolDoll, так замените это `@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)` на это `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']`. А еще лучше `@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']`

Comment: Пробовал, успеха не приносило

Comment: @FiolDoll, плохо значит пытались. Потому что `@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)` будет срабатывать на все сообщения, которые приходят от бота. Следовательно блок `help` никогда не будет выполнен

Comment: И код для создания таблицы в БД выполняется только 1 раз, поэтому весь код с `"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...` нужно удалить

Comment: @DeNRuDi Сделал, теперь работает. (вставил `@bot.message_handler(commands=["reg"])`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот более логичное решение (код не запускал, но думаю смысл будет понятен)

```
import telebot
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')

# Подключаемся к Базе Данных
def connect():
    db = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
    cu = db.cursor()
    return db, cu


# Создаём функцию, которая срабатывает при любом сообщении '/start'
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def echo_all(message):
    db, cu = connect()
    # Если пользователя в БД нету
    cu.execute(f"SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_id = ?",(message.from_user.id,))
    if cu.fetchone() is None:
        # Сохраняем его ID в БД
        cu.execute(f"INSERT INTO user VALUES(?, ?)", (message.from_user.id, 0))
        db.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{message.from_user.first_name}, я успешно зарегистрировал тебя в Базе Данных!')
    cu.close()
    db.close()

@bot.message_handler(commands=["help"])
def send_help(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Добро пожаловать {message.from_user}!")


# Запускаем бота
bot.polling()
```

Comment: У вас в строке `@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"]` отсутствует символ `)` в конце.

Comment: @Tehnorobot, да, исправил. Спасибо:)